# vectorize numpy mean across the slices of an array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize a function so that the output would be an array of means where each mean represents the mean of the values from 0-index of the input array?  Looping this is pretty straightforward but I am trying to be as efficient as possible. e.g. 0 = mean(0), 1 = mean(0-1), N = mean(0-N)

Comment: What is the "0-index" of an array is in this context?

Comment: the beginning of the array

Comment: Curious if either of the solutions posted here work for you?

Answer (score 4):

The intended operation could be *coined* as `cumulative averaging`. So, an obvious solution would involve `cumulative summation` and dividing those summations by the number of elements participating for each such summation. Thus, a vectorized implementation would involve [`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and then dividing by the number of participating elements that could be obtained with [`np.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and generalized for an ndarray, like so -

```
def cummean(A,axis):
    """ Cumulative averaging

    Parameters
    ----------    
    A    : input ndarray
    axis : axis along which operation is to be performed

    Output
    ------    
    Output : Cumulative averages along the specified axis of input ndarray
    """

    return np.true_divide(A.cumsum(axis),np.arange(1,A.shape[axis]+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use `pandas` there is `expanding_mean` which will work directly with a NumPy array:

```
In [10]: pandas.expanding_mean(np.arange(1, 11))
Out[10]: array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,  5.5])
```

This method also works column-wise:

```
In [11]: A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
                       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]).T

In [12]: A
Out[12]: 
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 2,  1],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 4,  1],
       [ 5,  1],
       [ 6,  1],
       [ 7,  1],
       [ 8,  1],
       [ 9,  1],
       [10,  1]])

In [13]: pandas.expanding_mean(A)
Out[13]: 
array([[ 1. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.5,  1. ],
       [ 2. ,  1. ],
       [ 2.5,  1. ],
       [ 3. ,  1. ],
       [ 3.5,  1. ],
       [ 4. ,  1. ],
       [ 4.5,  1. ],
       [ 5. ,  1. ],
       [ 5.5,  1. ]])
```